# Why does webpack ignore the index.js although it's in the same directory of my app.js, which is compiled fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am building a simple form with react, using webpack. I'm new to webpack and react, so there might be an obvious solution, but I just can't figure it out.

My code structure (simplified):

```
root:
- server.js
- webpack.config.js
- src:
-- App.js
-- index.js
- public:
-- index.html
-- bundle.js
```

In my `app.js` is only one Component. I have excluded the `ReactDOM.render` method into a file `index.js`. Since i've done that it doesn't work anymore. Before it worked just fine.

The App isn't rendered into my `index.html` anymore. I **guess** webpack compiles only my `app.js` file and ignores my `index.js`. But I can't know for sure.

When I include the `index.js` into my `App.js` everything works just fine.

```
// /src/App.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     form: 'firmenkontakt'
   }
 };

 render() {
   return (
     <div className={this.state}>
       <form method="post" id={this.state}>
                ...
            </form>
     </div>
   )
 }
}

export default App;
```

The rendering-file looks as follow:

```
// /src/index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

I wonder if anything is wrong about my `webpack.config.js`

```
// /webpack.config.js
let path = require('path');

const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/App.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
  },
  watch: true,
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test:/\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_module/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You've told webpack that App.js is the entry point so it'll start there and see what is needed. It can't guess that index.js is referencing App.js or needs it. You'll have to change your entry setting to index.js

Answer (score 0):

Your entry file should be `src/index.js' and it must import`App.js`